# how to print test and variable in python with no space between

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cmd

I have the following python line

```
for numbers in Alb:
    print("//site.com/",number.id,"")
```

But it prints like this

```
//site.com/ 118290167 
//site.com/ 105408368 
//site.com/ 100737801
```

What am i doing wrong to get the space and how can i remove the space after the test and before the Variable

Comment: Nothing to do with CMD - *Command Prompt (executable name cmd.exe) is the Microsoft supplied command line interpreter on OS/2, Windows CE, and all Microsoft Windows operating systems. Use this tag for questions regarding programming scripts or on commands available to run from the Command Prompt. Add tags for which version of Windows, and tags describing the task or issue. *.

Comment: Nothing to do with Windows - Writing software specific to the Microsoft Windows operating system: APIs, behaviors, etc. Note: GENERAL WINDOWS SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for numbers in Alb:
    print("//site.com/" + number.id)
```

This will concatenate the strings instead of providing them as parameters to the print function

Comment: I get ```TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str```

Comment: I got it now, ```    print("//site.com/" + str(number.id)) 
```